# Running GLCM through patches of an image in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, glcm

Is there a way to split an image into different boxes and run GLCM on each separate box? E.g. split a 1000 x 1000 image into 50 20 x 20 boxes.

I'm looking to pinpoint regions of an image which show homogeneity - and then localise my analysis. I suspect that you can use blockproc to do this, but I'm not sure how to write the 'fun' function so that it runs the GLCM code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this? I don't own the Image Processing Toolbox, so I can't try it...

```
for k = 1:50
  for l = 1:50
    G(k,l) = graycomatrix(A((k-1)*20+1:k*20, (l-1)*20+1:l*20));
  end
end
```

By the way – when you split a 1000x1000 image into 20x20 blocks, you'll end up with 2500 blocks.